# MySQL read-buffer-size overflow

Tags: mysql, buffer, my.cnf

What will happen if a low value was assigned in my.cnf to any of the per-thread buffers, when it fills?

I'm thinking of possible scenarios:

1. MySQL will gracefully call realloc for additional block with the same size.
2. A buffer overflow, causing thread to terminate
3. Unexpected behaviour, like incorrect sort (if sort-buffer-size is filled during the process)

Comment: read buffer is preemptive, so if it is filled already, new data replace the old one. If your dataset is too big to fit into buffer, no buffering occurs.

Comment: please answer as your comment and I will accept your answer.